# Stop VSCode Asking Me for SSH Password

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh

VSCode constantly asks me for unlocking my ssh key if i use it in a git repo. However, I don't have the intention of using ssh inside VSCode. Can I make it stop somehow, maybe by changing some settings?